# SQL Conditional Aggregation not returning all expected rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I've been trying to get a conditional aggregation running on one of my tables in SQL Server Management Studio and I've run across a problem: only one row is being returned when there should be 2.

```
SELECT ListID,
MAX(CASE WHEN QuestionName = 'Probability Value' THEN Answer END) AS 'prob',
MAX(CASE WHEN QuestionName = 'Impact Value' THEN Answer END) As 'impa',
MAX(CASE WHEN QuestionName = 'What is the Risk Response Strategy' THEN Answer END) AS 'strat',
MAX(CASE WHEN QuestionName = 'Response Comment' THEN Answer END) AS 'rrap'
FROM table1
GROUP BY ListID
```

By the information stored on the table is should return two rows, something like:

```
ListID | Prob | Impa | Strat | rrap |
   1      2      3     Admin   text1
   1      5      5     Elim    text2
```

but only the first row appears. I don't have any good leads at the moment, but I wonder if you good people might have spotted something obviously wrong with the initial query.

Comment: could you please provide some sample data of your table

Comment: @ZacWatkins You are only grouping by `ListID`, it's only going to return one row since your example shows two records with the same `ListID`, if you need both, you need to `Group By` more than just `ListID`

Comment: @ZacWatkins - what is the problem you are trying to solve , explain that better

Comment: Right! Of course, only grouping by listID is my problem, thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only group by is ListID and your 2 rows both have 1 on ListID, that's why they group up

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think it should return more than 1 row? You are grouping by `ListID` and getting the `MAX` answer for all these questions.

If you want more rows returned you will have to group by other columns/expressions as well. You can't expect `ListID` 1 to appear more than once if you grouped by `ListID` only.